# Inserting data into table SQL server

Tags: mysql, database

If I have 2 tables and Table 1 has a primary key(userID) AutoIncrement and Table 2 has a foreign Key(userID) to Table 1's (userID)

When I insert a new row into Table 1 first row will have userID = 1

Then if I insert again, userID = 2.

So how do I go about keeping Table 2's userID the same when inserting in Table 1. For instance, in Table 2, I am adding the password into another table.

My question is should I add an AUTOINCREMENT to Table 2(userID) and insert a new value into both tables when I create a user OR is there another way?

Comment: There's functionality in MySQL to help with this. Basically: Insert a new record into table 1, determine the new ID, then insert into Table2. 2 or 3  statements (depending), no funny business. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually insert data with correct id in Table2. There is no such built-in functionality in MySQL.

The algorithm is as follows:

1. Insert row in Table1.
2. Get Id of the new row.
3. Insert row with new id in Table2.

Comment: Yes the function for retrieving last id is built in ...  So long as it's a `PRIMARY KEY` -->   `LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this ... Assuming your ID is `PK` and `AI`

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (var1, var2 etc etc) VALUES ('val1', 'val2'  etc etc);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

To further it ..

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (var1, var2 etc etc) VALUES ('val1', 'val2'  etc etc);
SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO yourTable2 (id, var1, var2) VALUES (@last_id, 'blah', 'blah');
```